# Is it possible for ls to maintain the order of its inputs

Tags: ls, xargs

If I do `/usr/bin/which --all git`, it shows me all the occurrences of `git` in my `$PATH`, *where the first line shows the effective one*.

From the below picture, the `git` version in `/home/kmodi/stowed/bin/git` is the effective one.

Now I wanted to know the true file names of the results.

So for `/home/kmodi/stowed/bin/git`, which is a symlink, I wanted to know what that pointed to.

Doing `/usr/bin/which --all git | xargs \ls -Fpl` shows the symlink reference. But the output is confusing.. the original order of listed files is not retained! So now looking at that output (below), one might think that the version in `/cad/..` is the effective `git` binary path.

**Is there a way to make `xargs` retain that order?**

[image]

---

If it matters, I am using `tcsh` shell.

---

Thanks to the tip from John about `-n 1`, I finally have a solution that I like. It is messy.. *those quotes!* (thanks to `tcsh`), but it works.

```
alias whichall '/usr/bin/which --all \!* \\
                | xargs -n 1 \ls -Fpl --color=always \\
                | awk -v OFS="" '"'"'{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; print $0}'"'"' \\
                | \sed '"'"'/^$/d'"'"'; \\
               '
```

Now `whichall git` gives:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xargs` command did maintain the order of it's arguments - but it passed all of them to one instance of `ls`, which gave you output in alphabetical order, which it does by default. To get the behavior you want, add a `-n 1` argument to the `xargs` command to pass only one line of output to `ls` at a time, or if using the GNU implementation of `ls`, add a `-U` option to tell it not to sort the list of files.

Behavior of `ls`:

```
$ ls -lad /usr/bin /etc
drwxr-xr-x. 146 root root 12288 May 18 09:46 /etc
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root 57344 Dec 12 15:30 /usr/bin
```